# extending enum in initializer class_eval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I have a model inside gem that I reopen inside config/initializers.
I want to extend the enumeration for a certain field when I reopen the class.
it goes like this

=========my gem==========

```
class organisation < ActiveRecord::Base

  enum organisation_type:{
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
  }

end
```

=======my initializers==========

```
organisation.class_eval do

  enum organisation_type:{
    'c' => 3
  }

end
```

but it says that I cannot overwrite enumerate as it's already a final method or some sort. can anyone give me a way to extend the enum so that I can have a,b, and c option?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a new model that inherits the class 'Organization'. Inside the new model you can re-define the enum. For example:

```
class NewOrganisation < Organisation

  enum organisation_type:{
   'a' => 1,
   'b' => 2,
   'c' => 3
  }

end
```

Now, you can access all the methods of Organisation and re-defined enum 'organisation_type'.

Comment: the problem is I need it to have the same name(Organisation)